# Is there any way to speed up rendering time for one small change in a long list of elements?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

My example linked below shows a very large list of a grid of divs (1,000 x 20)
 and when clicking on one div, it will highlight only that one element. However,
 it seems there is significant overhead by VueJS in the rerendering which introduces a lag when clicking.

```
  <div class="row" v-for="row in rows">
    <div v-for="column in row.columns" :class="{red: isHighlighted(row,column)}" @click.prevent="setHighlighted({row: row.id, column: column.id})">
      <div>Value: {{column['value']}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Code Pen Example](https://codepen.io/weexpectedTHIS/pen/oqZNQQ)

Comment: I agree, 20K should just not be attempted, but I'm confused why it takes so long to RE-render the page when clicking on an element. All it has to do is update one div with one class. Re-running the method 20K times still shouldn't take long.

Comment: You can find a properly explanation here https://forum.vuejs.org/t/performance-issues-related-to-long-lists/21019/2
I think https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can speed it up by not doing something that requires an evaluation on every update. In your case, the `class` setting has to call a function for every box every time `row` or `column` changes.

I added the `style` as a member of the column, so that on highlighting, it can be found directly, rather than requiring each cell to notice the change to `highlighted`. However, this still didn't remove the lag.

After working on this for a while, I surmised that the `:class` setting was being re-evaluated on every update, even if it was not a function call. My earlier solution handled class-setting explicitly, and that avoided the `:class` issue. This solution uses a component for each cell, which avoids re-calculation because components only re-evaluate when their props change.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    rows: [],
    rowCount: 2000,
    highlighted: {
      row: null,
      column: null
    }
  },
  getters: {
    rows(state) {
      return state.rows;
    },
    rowCount(state) {
      return state.rowCount;
    },
    highlighted(state) {
      return state.highlighted;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setRows(state, rows) {
      state.rows = rows;
    },
    setHighlighted(state, highlighted) {
      state.highlighted = highlighted;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  data() {
    return {
      highlightedEntry: null,
      highlightedEl: null
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.setRows(
      Array.from(Array(this.rowCount).keys()).map(i => {
        return {
          id: i,
          columns: Array.from(Array(parseInt(20)).keys()).map(j => {
            return {
              id: j,
              value: Math.random().toPrecision(4),
              isHighlighted: false
            };
          })
        };
      })
    );
  },
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapGetters(["rows", "rowCount", "highlighted"])
  },
  components: {
    aCell: {
      props: ['rowId', 'column'],
      template: '<div :class="{red: column.isHighlighted}" @click="highlight">Value: {{column.value}}</div>',
      computed: {
        style() {
          return this.column.style;
        }
      },
      methods: {
        highlight() {
          this.$emit('highlight', this.rowId, this.column);
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...Vuex.mapMutations(["setRows", "setHighlighted"]),
    highlight(rowId, column) {
      if (this.highlightedEntry) {
        this.highlightedEntry.isHighlighted = false;
      }
      this.highlightedEntry = column;
      column.isHighlighted = true;
      this.setHighlighted({
        row: rowId,
        column: column.id
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row>* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    Cells: {{rowCount * 20}}
  </div>
  <div class="row" v-for="row in rows" :key="row.id">
    <div v-for="column in row.columns">
      <a-cell :row-id="row.id" :column="column" @highlight="highlight"></a-cell>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I would really prefer not to touch the dom directly like this, kind of defeats the purpose of using Vue.JS IMO. However, you may be right that it's the only way to optimize at this point without pagination.

Comment: There are other approaches you could take, notably putting an `isHighlighted` member into your column object and using that for your class binding.

Comment: @weexpectedTHIS I've updated my answer to be more Vue-ish.

Answer (score 0):

If each of your items has a unique property like an `id`, pass that to `:key="item.id"`:

```
<div v-for="column in row.columns" :key="column.id" ...
```

> When Vue is updating a list of elements rendered with v-for, by default it uses an “in-place patch” strategy. If the order of the data items has changed, instead of moving the DOM elements to match the order of the items, Vue will patch each element in-place and make sure it reflects what should be rendered at that particular index. This is similar to the behavior of track-by="$index" in Vue 1.x.

> This default mode is efficient, but only suitable when your list render output does not rely on child component state or temporary DOM state (e.g. form input values).

> To give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus reuse and reorder existing elements, you need to provide a unique key attribute for each item. An ideal value for key would be the unique id of each item. This special attribute is a rough equivalent to track-by in 1.x, but it works like an attribute, so you need to use v-bind to bind it to dynamic values (using shorthand here):

```
 <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
   <!-- content -->
 </div>
```

> It is recommended to provide a key with v-for whenever possible, unless the iterated DOM content is simple, or you are intentionally relying on the default behavior for performance gains.

> Since it’s a generic mechanism for Vue to identify nodes, the key also has other uses that are not specifically tied to v-for, as we will see later in the guide.

> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Comment: I've done this before but it did not improve the "re-rendering" when clicking on an element. I believe the key mostly has to do with the ordering of elements, and not as much on the props changing for a particular element.

Comment: Well, that's what Vue.js offers. I haven't had performance problems like you're experiencing, even when iterating over a similar amount of items. Try to experiment with different `id` values if your have several unique properties.